# How to not change default value of edittext in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am building a simple authentication app with a username and password for the android, so am using 2 edittexts, 1 for username and the other for password. 
These Edittexts by default has value 'username' and 'password'. So is there some way by which this value not be changed from the edittext by the user. Also if this is not possible can you guys suggest some other ways I can proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that what you want is to use the `hint=""` attribute of the EditText.

Comment: I used that, but whenever I type something the 'username' would disappear and then reappear if there was no more text in the edittext box.

Comment: So what is it exactly you want? An EditText in which the text cannot be changed?
If so, use a regular TextView and set the background to the same as the EditText.

Comment: Sorry if you felt the question was a bit vague, but I guess this is the solution which you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Textview` with the background similar to `EditText`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="username"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextBackground" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to keep your defaults "username" and "password" values in the edit-texts, without the user being able to edit them.

You could do:

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setClickable(false);
```

Which basically makes the editText non-editable. I hope I understood correctly your problem. Nevertheless, I recommend using a textView rather than an editText if you do not want user-interaction with your values.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the layout (xml):

```
android:enable="false"
```

you can do same but with code ....